# Problem opening excel doc from outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-excel-2007

When i open the excel file from an email in excel 2010 it opens a tab out like an email how do i get rid of this i cannot find anything in the views setting

[image]

sorry i have now added a screen shot i want to get rid of the email bit in excel as shown above

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. Posting a screen shot of the problem might help for example.

Comment: How are you opening the Excel file? Are you choosing "preview"?

Comment: not double clicking it for it to open up

Comment: sorry ment to say no i am just double clicking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the **Send To Recipient** command to your Quick Access Toolbar to toggle this feature on and off.

How To: [Microsoft Office Help - Customize the Quick Access Toolbar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-HA001234105.aspx)